# Given ordinal $\alpha \geq \omega_1$ does $\alpha \omega_1 = \omega_1 \alpha$

Tags: ordinals

As in the question, I am asked whether or not ordinal multiplication is commutative for an ordinal greater that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1$.

My reasoning was that it shouldn't:

Take $\alpha = \omega_1 ^{\omega}$, then we have $\omega_1 \alpha = \omega_1 ^{1+\omega} = \omega_1 ^{\omega} = \alpha$

But $\alpha\omega_1 = \omega_1 ^{\omega+1}$

However, I'm not very familiar with how $\omega_1$ might behave. Is it really true here that $\omega_1^{\omega} < \omega_1^{\omega + 1}$ or is there some property about the uncountability of $\omega_1$ that actually allows for equality here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\omega_1^{\omega + 1} = \omega_1^\omega \omega_1$ by definition of exponentiation, and $\omega_1 > 1$ clearly. Multiplication (and addition) on the *right* preserves strict equality, so $\omega_1^{\omega} \omega_1 > \omega_1^\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

As B. Mehta observes, you have indeed found a counterexample to the claim. However, there is an arguably simpler counterexample: $$\omega_1(\omega_1+1)=\omega_1^2+\omega_1\quad\mbox{but}\quad (\omega_1+1)\omega_1=\omega_1^2.$$

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this helps, since OP requires $a \geq \omega_1$.

Comment: @B.Mehta Derp, that was silly. We can still get a counterexample much smaller than $\omega_1^\omega$.

Comment: How have you concluded that $(\omega_1 + 1)\omega_1 = \omega_1^2$ since as far as I can tell ordinal multiplication isn't distributive when the sum is on the left?

Comment: @user366818 This is in fact an example of the **failure** of distributivity! Thinking of ordinals as linear orderings, remember that $\alpha\beta$ is the ordinal gotten by replacing each point in $\beta$ with a copy of $\alpha$; e.g. $2\omega=2+2+2+...$ ($\omega$-many times). So $(\omega_1+1)\omega_1=(\omega_1+1)+(\omega_1+1)+...$ ($\omega_1$-many times); but each "$+1$" is absorbed into the next $\omega_1$, so this is just $\omega_1^2$.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't constitute a proof from the formal definitions of ordinal arithmetic, but it's not hard to turn the above intuitive argument into a formal one.